# Scraping html table into a data frame

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have built a little scraper that directs to a page in a website through selenium and then is supposed to read the html table that is present on the final page into a data frame (or just a header page). I'm stuck on the last bit. I can open up the final page and I'm stuck. [image: html of final page]

This is the html output of the final page. The table headers are in the  tags and the observations are in the  tags. My code for the table is probably awful but here it is:

```
    df = pd.read_html(browser.get(table),header=0)
    print(df.head(n=6))
```

table is the url btw

The error I get is "TypeError: Cannot read object of type 'NoneType'".
I believe I am missing a step, and if anyone would be so kind as to point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: is the URL something you can share?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I had to get to the page by inputting a username and password. @BobHaffner

Comment: Ok.  BTW, I didn't notice this the first time, but read_html doesn't return a dataframe.  It returns a list of dataframes.  So df.head() won't work.  Don't think it matters though as i'm guessing it errors before then

Comment: Also, if table is the URL, shouldn't you just do `pd.read_html(table, header=0)`?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. I wasn't able to nest a get() call within the pd.read_html() call.

```
    browser.get(table)
    source = browser.page_source
    content = pd.read_html(source)
    df = pd.DataFrame(content)
```

Once I opened the browser to the page of the table I wanted, all I did was call the browser (which is really the chromedriver) and get the page_source. Then I was able to read the html and convert it to a dataframe.